# MySQL finding fuel consumtion in Travel Log table

Tags: mysql, sql, database

A travel log table consists of the following columns:

> Plate Number, kilometer, date, litters

Something like this:

```
Plate Number      kilometer      date      litters
    1                25           5          20
    1                ..           6          20
    1                ..           7          20
    1                ..           8          20
    1                200          9          20
```

Usually the table not sorted by plate number, but I can do that, I need to subtract starting kilometer for date (5) from ending kilometer for date (9), and then, getting sum of all litters, a result like this:

```
Plate Number      kilometer      date      litters
    1                175          NA         100
```

Here 175 = 200-25, and 100 =  SUM(20+20+20+20+20)

## Is there any query to do that?

Comment: How do you determine if the value in `kilometer` is a starting or ending value?

Comment: I think the result of kilometer should be `175 = 200 - 25` instead of `195= 200 - 5`.

Answer (score 4):

It's trivial using group by(Obviously the Kilometer will always increase).

```
select 
    Plate_Number
   ,max(Kilometer) - min(Kilometer) as kilometer
   ,'NA' as date
   ,sum(litters) as litters 
from 
    log_table 
group by 
    Plate_Number
```

Answer (score 2):

This query will give you all the results you need, you can change date to variables in case you need different dates.

```
SELECT 
Plate_Number,
MAX(kilometer) as max,MIN(kilometer) as min, (max - min) as result,
sum(litters) as litters, 
date 
FROM 
log_table
WHERE 
date 
BETWEEN
5 
AND 
9
GROUP BY 
Plate_Number
```

**EDIT**

In case you always need max and min date, you can change it like

```
WHERE
date
BETWEEN
(SELECT DISTINCT min(date) FROM log_table)
AND 
(SELECT DISTINCT max(date) FROM log_table)
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:
select `Plate Number`, max(Kilometer) - 5 as kilometer, 'NA' as date, sum(litters) as litters
from log_table
where date >=5 and date <= 9
group by `Plate Number`
Please put Plate number in back-ticks.